# UWP WebView C# event from html

Tags: webview, uwp

Can I catch a JavaScript event happening in a html in the c# code?

Consider the following example, I am having an html with a button inside it and in my app I am viewing it through `WebView` and I have a c# code to be executed when that particular button is clicked.

How can I catch the the clicking of button in c# code?

```
<html>
  <head>
       .......
  </head>

  <body>
       ........
       <button id="idOfButton" name="NameOfButton"></button>
       ........
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I catch the the clicking of button in c# code?

We can not catch the the clicking of button in C# code.

We should be able to add the [`ScriptNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ScriptNotify) event of the `WebView`. A hosted HTML page can fire the `ScriptNotify` event in your Windows Store app when the page calls window.external.notify and passes a string parameter.

For example:

```html
<WebView x:Name="WebViewControl" ScriptNotify="WebViewControl_ScriptNotify" Source="ms-appx-web:///scriptNotify_example.html"/>
```

Code behind:

```cs
void WebViewControl_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    // Be sure to verify the source of the message when performing actions with the data.
    // As webview can be navigated, you need to check that the message is coming from a page/code
    // that you trust.
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```

The scriptNotify_example.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>This is a simple test page for window.external.notify().</p>
    <input id="payload" type="text" value="Payload string" />
    <button onclick="window.external.notify(payload.value)">Call window.external.notify</button>
    <p />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: will it help if i use win js for writing app?

Comment: @AravindBelagaje We should be able to change the html. We can also use it in WinJS.